# TfLite for Microcontrollers giving hybrid error

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I converted my keras .h5 file to a quantized tflite in order to run on the new OpenMV Cam H7 plus but when I run it I get an error saying "Hybrid Models are not supported on TFLite Micro."

I'm not sure why my model is appearing as hybrid; the code I used to convert is below:

```
model = load_model('inceptionV3.h5')

# Convert the model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the TF Lite model.
with tf.io.gfile.GFile('inceptionV3_openmv2.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

I'd appreciate if someone could guide me if I'm doing something wrong or if there is a better way to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
import tensorflow as tf
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file("inceptionV3.h5")
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE]
converter.target_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
tf_model = converter.convert() 
open ("inceptionV3_openmv2.tflite" , "wb") .write(tf_model)
```

Comment: I tried this but the function isn't there anymore. I'm using tensorflow 2 and this is a tf 1 function.

Comment: In TensorFlow 2, there is similar way to convert the model, you can see in this guide link https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/get_started

Comment: If issue is not resolved, you can add your issue in TensorFlow Github  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new?template=60-tflite-converter-issue.md